# ClearView doesn't work well when dropping the viewholder ItemTouchHelper.Callback

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, itemtouchhelper

So I've created an interface extending ItemToucHelper.Callback() and when I move my viewholder it changes the color of the stroke and when I drop it, it should return to the normal color.
The problem is that after dropping it doesn't change the color even though the Log shows it calls the clearview methodm then after "touching" the item sometimes it returns to normal.

**Relevant code**

Custom class for Callback

```
class NoteItemTouchHelperCallback(
    private val itemTouchHelper: ItemTouchHelperAdapter
): ItemTouchHelper.Callback() {

    override fun clearView(recyclerView: RecyclerView, viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder) {
        super.clearView(recyclerView, viewHolder)
        Log.i(TAG, "Clear View")
        viewHolder.itemView.itemCardView.apply {
            changeStrokeColor(R.color.strokeCard)
            changeStrokeWidth(2)
        }
    }

    override fun onSelectedChanged(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder?, actionState: Int) {
        super.onSelectedChanged(viewHolder, actionState)
        if(actionState == ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_DRAG){
            viewHolder?.itemView?.itemCardView?.apply {
                Log.i(TAG, "On Selected")
         //I commented this and it's not the problem, but I know onSelectedChanged can be helpful here to solve it
                //changeStrokeColor(R.color.strokeCardSelected)
                //changeStrokeWidth(5)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onMove(
        recyclerView: RecyclerView,
        viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
        target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    ): Boolean {
        itemTouchHelper.onItemMove(viewHolder.adapterPosition, target.adapterPosition, viewHolder)
        return true
    }
}
```

Interface that will be implemented in MainActivity

```
interface ItemTouchHelperAdapter {

    fun onItemMove(fromPosition: Int, toPosition: Int, viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder)

    fun onItemSwiped(position: Int)
}
```

MainActivity

```
class MainActivity : BaseActivity<MainViewModel, ActivityMainBinding>(), ItemTouchHelperAdapter {
    override fun onItemMove(fromPosition: Int, toPosition: Int, viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder) {
        val noteList = mAdapter?.getNoteList()
        val note = noteList?.get(fromPosition)
        if(note!=null){
            noteList.removeAt(fromPosition)
            noteList.add(toPosition, note)

            Log.i(TAG, "Change position")
            viewHolder.itemView.itemCardView.apply {
                changeStrokeColor(R.color.strokeCard)
                changeStrokeWidth(5)
                Log.i(TAG, "Change UI card")
            }
        }
        mAdapter?.notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition)
    }
}
```

I tried to put the relevants thing that matter when it comes to the action of moving the item.

Question: What am I missing in the code?

Edit: The clearview takes effect after locking and unlocking the phone. Why does this happen?